# How to correctly level a raised floor built on an old garage floor?

Tags: subfloor, leveling

So, I've already tried and failed at this twice and if I'm going to rip up the floor again I want to make sure I do it right this time.

I made this room in my basement that used to be a garage and the floor (because it was a garage) it's pitched down about a decent amount (I forget but it's close to an inch). I read that the best way it so cut some 2by material and then shim it up until it's level but after doing this and it settling (winter maybe) my floor is really bouncy now as some spots are lower. It's very annoying as when anyone walks in the room everything shakes. When I installed heat (hot water) under the floor this winter I again tried to fix it by gluing shims this time and adding spray foam under the joists but within a couple of months, the floor is back to be bouncy again, this time maybe worse.

So, if I 'm going to take up the floor and furniture again what's the best approach to make sure I don't have to do this again? Here are some pictures of the initial build and the last time when I added insulation and spray foam.

To make things more complicated a wall and cabinets are built in that can not be removed. So, I can't remove the entire floor and have to just take up large sections of the plywood and work with that.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: how are these 2x4 secured to the wall and floor?   Why didn't you use 2x4s that were long enough?

Comment: With 2x4s they need to be supported along entire length.  Can not just use slims part way and have some of 2x4 raised above floor with air/empty space below.

Comment: What's the problem? Just bounce? Add shims and construction glue.

Comment: @isherwood - floor in current state is almost impossible to shim right.   Also hard to secure it or the shims.

Comment: how much bounce are we talking about?  Does the floor deflect downwards when you walk on it or jump on it?  Was your whole sleeper assembly just floating on the foam or did you glue and screw it to the concrete?

Comment: Pretty much the entire floor deflects probably because there is a void in certain areas now. The foam in the photos is in between the sleepers and not under it, there is spray foam under some spots but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a bunch of 6" x 3/8" galvanized lag screws. Pilot though your joists at intervals with a 1/4" or 5/16" bit, then run screws in to lift and level the joists. Cut of the protruding portion flush with a hack saw.

With that room size, every joist needs at least two support points (plus the outer ends). Don't span more than about 4'.

I would pull a carpenter's line down the center of the room, spaced above the joists with blocks at each end. Match the space all the way across.

Comment: Isn't the floor under the sleepers a concrete slab, are you suggesting putting the lag screws into the concrete to level the sleepers? or is the idea that the lag screw become little feet that help to level the sleepers and then you reciprocate the top of the lag screws flush with the top of the sleepers?  and you'd only use these "feet" where the current sleepers are not level or have deflection?

Comment: That's how I read it, they would act as little feet.

Comment: The lags will act as adjustable legs. With the joist blocking and the subfloor screwed down it should be quite stable. They're not really sleepers anymore since they're suspended.

Comment: I wonder if OP could set the lags, as you suggest, to level, and then stuff cement under the 2x4 (or lay the 2x4 on cement) for more stability and fewer screws. Sort of how you set a a bathtub.

Comment: I don't know about this.   This floor looks attached in a very shoddy way and for all intensive purposes, its floating.   Putting lag screws down, I see the logic.   What I would be afraid of is that they would lose levelness during seasonal changes as wood moves vs concrete and then the lag screws are tap dancing when you walk.   Maybe there is a way to modify your answer but I wouldn't just leave it like this.   Also complicating this is the sistering of the runs... which for the life of me I don't understand why he made this more complicated by doing something harder.

Comment: I generally agree. OP will need to deal with overall stability issues before _any_ solution is viable. P.s. "[intents and purposes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/intents-and-purposes-versus-intensive-purposes)". ;)